# to prove that a function is a Differentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis

let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function in $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$.

In addition, $f'(x)$ is defined for every $x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta),x_0\notin(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$

In addition, i know that $\underset{x_0}{lim}    f'(x)=L$

how can i prove that  $f(x)$    Differentiable in $x_0$ ?

at first, i thought that we can use the Mean value theorem,but i'm not sure if the conditions are sufficient.

Comment: There seems to be some typo there. Surely you can't have $x_0\not\in (x_0-\delta;x_0+\delta)$.

Comment: It seems to me that when the question is fixed [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070858/show-that-if-lim-x-to-afx-a-then-fa-exists-and-equals-a/1070896#1070896) will be a duplicate.

Comment: hi Git, is i saw the answer there, is it ok to use the Mean value theorem also in my case? as stated in your link?

Comment: @Amit Yes.${{}}$

Comment: thank you very much. case closed.